# Error creating new Meteor APP in Windows 8.1: future.js:398:15

Tags: windows, meteor, iron-router

I've been working in Meteor for some weeks, creating some applications to test it and assure that everything works fine before adopting it for the company. Yesterday I created and Meteor application in my Windows 8.1 with no problem, but today with no apparent change on my system, when I do any “meteor create [x]” or even “meteor update” it crashes:

Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\os.json' at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x8632\d ev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15) at Object.wrapper [as readFile] (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.window s.x86_32\tools\files.js:1350:24) at C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isopack.js:693: 15 at Array.forEach (native) at Function..each..forEach (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x 86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11) at [object Object]..extend.loadUnibuildsFromPath (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool \1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\isopack.js:680:7) at [object Object]..extend.initFromPath (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt- os.windows.x86_32\tools\isopack.js:606:17) at springboard (C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\ma in.js:458:15) at C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\main.js:1023:5

If I try to run my previous applications It works fine, but it do not allow me to create new apps.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that one was hard!

Uninstalling meteor and installing it again allowed Meteor to work.
After that, installing the pluigins of my project moved it to the same state.
I’ve found that the problem was that I was using PowerShell instead of “cmd”.

The right procedure to make it work was:

1. Uninstall Meteor
2. Install it again
3. Go to the app folder (in cmd as admin) and do meteor update
4. Then meteor (and in my case add some packages because of changes of dependences in versions).
5. All running OK

If you do the same thing with PowerShell step 3 (or 4 before 3) makes meteor stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install on a drive that either has no space, or has no permission to write. Meteor run as Admin and/or check for disk space. [Reference](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-enoent-stat-cusersuserappdataroamingnpm-on-windows-7).

*Using Google Translate.*

Comment: I'm in a CMD as administrator and there are 4GB in c: and 198GB in d: (where I'm trying to create the app).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar and ended up being a permission related issue.  To confirm that it is indeed permission related, try to open the command line as an Administrator and do the update and see if you have the same problem.

If that does solve the issue, check the permission for C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool and see if it is accessible by the user you are logged in as.

Comment: Yes it is. I've Just added everyone total controll to all the contents and fails (running in a console as admin).